# Photoswipe doesn't display some images in Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, photoswipe

I have a gallery of images, and by clicking on them, Photoswipe is opened. When I begin to list the images, some of them are not displayed, I can see only a black screen instead of an image. But when I reload the page, click the image - all of them are displayed in Photoswipe slider. Here is the code of my page:

```
<div class="row collapse full-width gallery-images" data-amount="<%= images.length %>">
  <% images.each_with_index do |image, index| %>
    <% if (index + 1) % 5 == 0 || (index + 2) % 5 == 0 %>
      <div class="large-6 columns">
        <%= link_to image_tag(image.file_name.url(:gallery),
                              alt: File.basename(image.file_name.url),
                              class: 'gallery-item'), '#' %>
      </div>
    <% else %>
      <div class="large-4 columns">
        <%= link_to image_tag(image.file_name.url(:gallery),
                              alt: File.basename(image.file_name.url),
                              class: 'gallery-item'), '#' %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</div>

<script>
  let galleryImages = $('.gallery-item');
  let galleryImagesArray = [];

  function collectArrayOfImages(image, array) {
    let imageSrc = image.attr('src');
    let img = new Image();
    img.src = imageSrc;
    array.push({
      src: imageSrc,
      w: img.width,
      h: img.height
    })
  }

  galleryImages.each(function () {
    collectArrayOfImages($(this), galleryImagesArray);
  });

  function photoswipeInit(e, i, array) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // init Photoswipe

    let pswpElement = document.querySelectorAll('.pswp')[0];

    // build items array
    let items = array;

    // define options (if needed)
    let options = {
      // optionName: 'option value'
      // for example:
      index: i, // start at first slide
      history: false
    };

    // Initializes and opens PhotoSwipe
    let gallery = new PhotoSwipe( pswpElement, PhotoSwipeUI_Default, items, options);
    gallery.init();
  }

  for(let i = 0; i < galleryImages.length + 1; i++) {
    galleryImages.eq(i).click(function (e) {
      photoswipeInit(e, i, galleryImagesArray);
    });
  }
</script>
```

Can it be `turbolinks`, if yes, how can I fix it? Any ideas what can it be? Thanks ahead.

Comment: Where are you pictures stored ? It could be a problem with CORS or the asset pipeline (if the problem happens only in production)

Comment: The images are stored on the server, there is no CORS. And yes, the issue appears on production, as well as on the development

Comment: On the server you mean in the assets/images folder of your rails app ?

Comment: Not in assets/images, I upload images using `carrierwave` gem. The folder is located in public/uploads

Comment: I am not sure uploading images to your slug make them persistent. I personaly upload user assets to an AWS bucket, and regarding my app assets, I put them in assets/images. Probably you shouldn't upload directly to your Rails app, but I am not too sure about this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found that in the array of images width and height were set to 0. So I had to put my function into a `setTimeout`:

```
function collectArrayOfImages(image, array) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      let imageSrc = image.attr('src');
      let img = new Image();
      img.src = imageSrc;
      array.push({
        src: imageSrc,
        w: img.width,
        h: img.height
      });
    }, 1000);
  }
```

It seems, that for some reason the function wasn't able to handle the process of filling the array.

Comment: Your notice upon setting height as 0 is correct, i bet.